# Как поправить тень?

Tags: html, css

чтобы было как на скрине ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.box {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 30px -30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px -30px 30px -30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eaque deleniti quia doloremque a ipsa ab libero quasi et iste. Doloribus voluptatibus sit veniam, eum assumenda, molestias maiores culpa eaque.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы тень была подобной попробуйте сделать как то так:

```
box-shadow: 0px 20px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0px -20px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]